# How to embed ruby in html inside ruby file?

Tags: html, ruby

I have a ruby file which I use to send email. I am using the code from a tutorial as follows:

```
 require 'net/smtp'
 test_arr = ["test", "test1"]

 message = <<MESSAGE_END
 From: Private Person <me@fromdomain.com>
 To: A Test User <test@todomain.com>
 MIME-Version: 1.0
 Content-type: text/html
 Subject: SMTP e-mail test

 This is an e-mail message to be sent in HTML format

 <b>This is HTML message.</b>
 <h1>This is headline.</h1>

 //Here I want to iterate through the Array test_arr and create a h1 element for each element in array

 <h1> test </h1>
 <h1> test1 </h1>
 MESSAGE_END

 Net::SMTP.start('localhost') do |smtp|
 smtp.send_message message, 'me@fromdomain.com', 
                         'test@todomain.com'
 end
```

I have tried <% to inject ruby code to iterate the array but does not seem to work. How could I iterate through the test_arr Array inside that HTML message?

Comment: You will need to include erb and use it to format the template.

Answer (score 1):

Save the file as `.html.erb` to use embedded ruby codes with `<%= ruby_code %>` in html message.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use something like `erb` to create it as template.

Something like this should work.

```
require 'net/smtp'
require 'erb' 

 test_arr = ["test", "test1"]

 message = <<MESSAGE_END
 From: Private Person <me@fromdomain.com>
 To: A Test User <test@todomain.com>
 MIME-Version: 1.0
 Content-type: text/html
 Subject: SMTP e-mail test

 This is an e-mail message to be sent in HTML format

 <b>This is HTML message.</b>
 <h1>This is headline.</h1>

 <% test_arr.each() do |ta| %>
    <h1><%=ta%></h1>  
 <% end %>

 MESSAGE_END
 # create a renderer to parse our template 
 renderer = ERB.new(message)
 Net::SMTP.start('localhost') do |smtp|
 smtp.send_message renderer.result(), 'me@fromdomain.com', 
                         'test@todomain.com'

 end
```

notice that you need to `require 'erb'` in your script,  create the template, in this case a simple block to iterate over the array.  You then need to create a renderer from the template with `Erb.new(template_name)`. Once you have the renderer, you need to  call `#result` on it to get the rendered output.  You can look at the erb documentation for more information (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html)

Answer (score 0):

Put a line:

```
test_arr.map{|e| "<h1>#{e}</h1>"}.join($/)
```

in the relevant position.

Alternatively, you can use my [`dom` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/dom):

```
require "dom"

message = [
  <<~MESSAGE_END,
    From: Private Person <me@fromdomain.com>
    To: A Test User <test@todomain.com>
    MIME-Version: 1.0
    Content-type: text/html
    Subject: SMTP e-mail test

    This is an e-mail message to be sent in HTML format
  MESSAGE_END
  "This is HTML message.".dom(:b),
  "This is headline.".dom(:h1),
  test_arr.dom(:h1, nil),
].dom
```